# Laravel 5 unique validation in edit field with different primary key

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using the request feature in Laravel 5, and I can create a new whitelist item which works.

This is the rules for the edit function, and I need it to ignore the unique email field, when this hasn't been altered.

I am using what it says in the docs and setting my rules as follows

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email'=> 'required|email|unique:whitelists,whitelistID,'.$this->segment('2'),
        'level' => 'required',
        'position' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `whitelists` where `whitelistID` = te2st@test.com and `id` <> 3)
```

The column uses whitelistID as its primarykey and this is set in the Whitelist model using

```
protected $primaryKey = 'whitelistID';
```

Any idea why this is defaulting to 'id'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong with the arguments of `unique`. This should work better:

```
'email'=> 'required|email|unique:whitelists,email,'.$this->segment('2').',whitelistID',
```